# Kubernetes Configmap Error validating data: unknown

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, configmap

This is my config kubernetes to create the configmap

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fileprocessing-acracbsscan-configmap
data:
  SCHEDULE_RUNNING_TIME: '20'
```

The kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-29T23:15:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

But I have the error: error validating data: unknown; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I don't know the unknown error and how can I resolve it

Comment: This sample configmap looks OK. Although: one way to trigger some validation error here, would be to forget some quotes in your ConfigMap: If values for any given key could be casted as an integer for some reason (eg: 20), it should be surrounded by quotes. Same goes for boolean and lookalikes (true, false, yes, no). The sample given in your post is OK though.

Comment: Can you please share actual error you are getting.  Also can you share k8s version used by running kubectl version.   Earlier one shared had only client version and it’s saying 1.7.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, You did not publish the deployment, So to be clear, the Deployment.yaml should reference this config map

```
envFrom: 
  - configMapRef: 
      name: fileprocessing-acracbsscan-configmap
```

Also, I'm not sure but try to put the data on quotes.

```
"SCHEDULE_RUNNING_TIME": "20"
```

Use `kubectl describe po <pod_name> -n <namespace>` in order to get a clearer view on what's the status of the failure.

Try also `kubectl get events -n <namespace>` To get all events of current namespace, maybe it will clear the reason also.

Comment: there's no deployment involved, as far as I can tell. Issue is with creating a configmap. you won't get any event either, then